# view content filtered by taxonomy children

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I`m having a view block displayed on node page. In this block i want to show only other nodes that have the same child taxonomy selected.

I tried with contextual Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)

and those settings and is not working https://www.screencast.com/t/b8GJftJSanwA

The taxonomy looks like this

```
parent term1
- term1
- term2

parent term2
- term3
- term4
```

And on node are selects both parent and child.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are term2 and parent term2 the same? In effect making this 3 level Taxonomy? I guess you'd have it structured differently then.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your question, showing only nodes that have child terms, and getting the Contextual filter to work.

### List only nodes that have child terms

This part of the question can be solved by using a regular Filter `Has taxonomy term` and then select only the 2nd level from the list with the Operator set to `is one of`.

The same applies if you add a filter `Content: YourTaxonomyField` instead of the `Has taxonomy term`.

### Contextual taxonomy filter

With the main filter taking care of the depth, you don't need the Depth one as the Contextual filter.

Add `Content: Has taxonomy term ID` as the Contextual filter. Your example didn't have it set up correctly. It should be:
    When the filter value is NOT available
    **Provide default value**
    **Taxonomy term ID from URL**
    Only tick **Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks**
    **Filter to items that share any term**
    Under **More**
    **Allow multiple values** if your nodes can be tagged with more than one term at a time.

Don't forget to place your Block and adjust Block settings for the Contextual filter.